# ng-init not working inside link function of directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

According to this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sbx979prPBWU1AqFP478?p=preview), using `ng-init` in a directive won't execute a function assigned to scope inside link, but it will if I do it in controller.

Can anyone explain this?

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('linkDir', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    template: 'Link: <p ng-init="initLink()">{{ linkmsg  }}</p>',
    link: function(scope){
      scope.initLink = function(){
        scope.linkmsg = 'link function executed'
      }
    }
  };
});

app.directive('controllerDir', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    template: 'Controller: <p ng-init="initController()">{{ controllermsg  }}</p>',
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.initController = function(){
        $scope.controllermsg = 'controller function executed';
      }
    }
  };
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <link-dir></link-dir>
    <controller-dir></controller-dir>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has to due with how Angular's directives work. The linkage between the `scope` and the DOM element is a little bit complex to explain, but making a long story short, if you use controllers, the `scope` will be immediately created with the `initController` property, while if you use the `link` attribute, the scope will only be **populated after** it as been linked to the DOM element (this means `initLink` will be *undefined* during the `ng-init`).

In order to avoid these problems, don't use the `ngInit` directive, as stated on [Angular's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties
>   of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should
>   use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

Stick with Controllers if you need to init properties on the `scope`.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. I'm using ng-init to access an ng-form, which is automatically published to the scope, but isn't populated until after a controller has run. Do you have any suggestions for that issue?

Comment: What is exactly the requirement to populate the form after the Controller **has been** created? Can't you just populate it while the controller **is being** created? [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/frVSPssQOOs1vn6auNBr?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

With newer versions of Angular you can work around this by adding an ng-if to the element the ng-init is on so it gets evaluated when the function is available:

```
template: 'Link: <p ng-if="initLink" ng-init="initLink()">{{ linkmsg  }}</p>',
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/qGjPZ4P3OjIn8rU2cufQ?p=preview

Comment: Adding `ng-if` works for me (AngularJs 1.7.2). Thanks.

Comment: But then I found AngularJs created a new `scope` and I lost the reference to the original scope--it becomes a child scope.